# What happen when we receive a truncated DNS response?

Tags: sockets, dns

I am coding a very simple program to send CERT query and receive response from a DNS by UDP and using wireshark for debugging. I send the query as an hex string and receive response from the same socket but, even I can see the complete string (response) in wireshark, the response printed by my program is truncated. Can anyone explain to me what exactly happen when receiving a response?. I measure the response is the same query I sent!. Please give an advice, something is wrong in my code and do not know how a response should be caught. Thanks.

```
char recv_buffer[4096]; //to allocate the response

//sending query and receiving response 
to = sendto(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &sock_addr, sizeof(sock_addr));
printf("sent %d bytes to 140.113.216.171\n", to);

int len = sizeof(recv_buffer);
bzero(&recv_buffer, len); //filling with 0 the recv_buffer

from = recvfrom(sock, recv_buffer, len, 0, NULL, NULL);
printf("received %d bytes from 140.113.216.171\n", from);

//Printing the string received
for(int c=0;c<from;c++){
   printf("%c",recv_buffer[c]);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the response is really the same as request? DNS packet structure is firm and the same fields are in identical places. With printing binary data as characters you will likely miss principal details. Instead, you should do basic decoding of packet structure and print numerically at least: flags, rcode, qdcount, ancount, aucount, adcount.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Printing the string received
for(int c=0;c<to;c++){
```

you probably meant `from` not `to` here, since you want to have the number of bytes received, not sent.

Comment: Thanks @Steffen, I did not notice that, let me edit that part. However the problem is still the same because I am receiving the same response, I am printing the correct array.

Comment: Check if the length of the message you see in wireshark matches `from` and check that you actually print `from` characters. And please note that %c prints the character as binary, not hex, so any binary stuff (like \r, \0) will not show up as expected.

Comment: I see, actually I am receiving a data length of zero in my response and the string I am printing is only part of the message(it gave me back the query). Question is why I am receiving nothing in my response is the query is sent without problems.

Thanks for the prints advice, actually I need to print in decimal, I still have to figure out how to print the binary stuff correctly.

Comment: Sorry, but your description is too confusing. Please add error checking everywhere and maybe meditate a bit more about the code and the documentation for the functions you use before asking others, so that trivial bugs will not happen.

Comment: Sorry, I am really newbie on this, it is not that easy for me to figure it out, I appreciate your help and your advice. I will follow it and come back with a more clear questions. Thanks for your time.